# T SQL to join record dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, business-intelligence

Can someone help me out with the following scenario. I am using SQL Server 2008r2.  I need sql server query to get the expected result.  Here is what I tried to do:

```
DECLARE @ProjectInvoice TABLE(InvoiceID INT, ProjectID INT, InvoiceAmount float)
DECLARE @ProjectBudget TABLE(ProjectBudgetID INT, ProjectID INT, BudgetAmount float)
INSERT INTO @ProjectBudget VALUES(11,1,100000),(12,1,50000)
INSERT INTO @ProjectInvoice VALUES (12345,1,25000)
,(12346,1, 30000) 
,(12347,1, 40000) 
,(12348,1, 30000)
,(12349,1, 10000)

select * from @ProjectBudget
select * from @ProjectInvoice
```

Expected result:

```
-- Expected Result
--InvoiceID ProjectID InvoiceAmount ProjectBudgetID BugetAmountLeft 
--  12345   1           25k         11              75k  -- > 100k(original budget) - 25k   
--  12346   1           30k         11              45k --> 75k( budget amount left after first invoice) - 30k
--  12347   1           40k         11              5k  --> 45k - 40k
--  12348   1           5k          11              0k  --> now only 5k is left budget, whereas we have 30k to deduct, deduct 5k from projectBudget11 
--  12348   1           25k         12              25k --> and the rest 25k from project Budget 12
--  12349   1           10k         12              15k
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.InvoiceID, p.ProjectID, p.InvoiceAmount, sm.ProjectBudgetID, 
sm.BudgetAmount - sm.amt AS runningTot
FROM @ProjectInvoice AS p
INNER JOIN (SELECT i.InvoiceID, b.projectBudgetID, b.BudgetAmount,
        SUM(i.InvoiceAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY b.ProjectBudgetID ORDER BY     
i.InvoiceId) AS amt
FROM @ProjectBudget AS b
INNER JOIN @ProjectInvoice AS i ON b.ProjectID = i.ProjectID) as sm ON p.InvoiceID = sm.InvoiceId
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'order'

Comment: Hmm. It works on my machine. Double check spacing and try it again? Here is a link to how to use OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER BY ) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt work. need to take first record of @projectBudget and decut invoiceamount from it. Once BudgetAmount reaches zero, pick the next budget record for the same project and start deducting the rest of invoice amount from it.

Comment: How big is the data set you are working with? There are a couple of ways you could do it. One is to use cursors. Another is to pull the fields and add an artificial id using ROW_NUMBER() to it. Then pull the same set of rows with ROW_NUMBER - 1 on it and join the two. Now you have the data from the prior row with the current row. You just have to add a case statement to make use of it at the right time. Not sure how it would work on a large dataset though.